# Basis approach for Login and then listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I'm working on an Android app that will display a ListView with items loaded from the web.
The ListView must be displayed after logging in to the app.

What I've done so far:

- I created a Main Activity with tabs on the top.
- In one of the tabs (activity's) you have to log in.
- Then I use the AsyncTask to do the authenticating in the background.

Now that's what I've done so far.
I then need to make the following:

When the username and password meet requirements, the app should start a NEW activity, that will show the ListView with the remote items from the web. I need this to be done in a proper fashion, so i will also use an AsyncTask to do this. The Problem is...

I don't know how to approach this. Because when I verify the username it will load... and it will load again when it's loading the list items.. Is there a way to get this all working nicely and within the tabs interface as it currently is?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I completely understand what you are asking for.

As far as I can tell though, you want to add a listview tab AFTER authenticating. So just use [TabHost.newTabSpec()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#newTabSpec%28java.lang.String%29) to make a new tab once your async task returns that login was successful.

Sorry if I misunderstood. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thnx for the help... I'ts kinda difficult to explain. The thing is.. I want to login to the app.. Then it will load that authentication on the background so giving me a loading progressdialog. Then after logging in is done.. I need to download the list items from the web.. So that also gives me a progressdialog. So when you login correctly it will give you 2 times a progessdialog view one after the other. And I think that this will look odd to the user, and just in general.. So that's basically the question.. Is there a way.. to do this properly so you have just one progressdialog .. Thxn

Comment: Well I haven't used async tasks much, but couldn't you just put both of those into the doInBackground part of your async tasks & publish your progress as you choose? Then if authentication fails, you can just "cancel" the async task before it reaches the tab part. login == 1st half; tab == 2nd half.